# Compare strings and print out matches (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

Say I have an array of 3 strings:

```
strings = ["/I/love/bananas", "/I/love/blueberries", "/I/love/oranges"]
```

I want to compare my 3 strings and print out this new string:

```
new_string = "/I/love"
```

I don't want to match char by char, only word by word. Do anyone have a smart way to do that?

As a token of good will I have made this ugly code to show what functionality I am looking for:

```
strings = ["/I/love/bananas", "/I/love/blueberries", "/I/love/oranges"]
benchmark = strings.first.split("/")
new_string = []

strings.each_with_index do |string, i|
  unless i == 0
    split_string = string.split("/")
    split_string.each_with_index do |elm, i|
      final_string.push(elm) if elm == benchmark[i] && elm != final_string[i]
    end
  end
end

final_string = final_string.join("/")

puts final_string # => "/I/love"
```

Comment: when you want to output `"/I/love"`?what things you want to compare? based on what result you want to produce the final output?

Comment: Hi. I want to compare the string match. If e.g. benchmark[1] is "love", and all the other strings have "love" at index 1, I want to print "love" to my new_string. Now that I think about it though, my examplified code sucks, because it will break my logic if I add a string like e.g. "I/love/bananas/as/well", or just one more "I/love/bananas".

Comment: added one answer. Hope it would help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the same basic approach as @iAmRubuuu, but handles more than three strings in the input and is more concise and functional.

```
strings.map{ |s| s.split('/') }.reduce(:&).join('/')
```

Comment: good one! `strings = ["/I/love/bananas", "/I/love/blueberries", "/I/love/oranges"]
a = strings.each_with_object([]) { |i,a| a << i.split('/') }.reduce(:&).join('/')
p a`

Comment: forgot about `inject`/`reduce` for binary operations. :D

Comment: Yes, that is also a great answer. Thanks both.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the below:

```
p RUBY_VERSION
strings = ["/I/love/bananas", "/I/love/blueberries", "/I/love/oranges"]
a = strings.each_with_object([]) { |i,a| a << i.split('/') }
p (a[0] & a[1] & a[2]).join('/')
```

*or*

```
strings = ["/I/love/bananas", "/I/love/blueberries", "/I/love/oranges"]
a = strings.each_with_object([]) { |i,a| a << i.split('/') }.reduce(:&).join('/')
p a
```

*Output:*

```
"2.0.0"
"/I/love"
```

Comment: There's no need for `each_with_object` and `<<` when `map` will do. Your final reduction only works when there are exactly three elements in the original. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15723691/1074296) for a cleaner approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
str = ["/I/love/bananas", "/I/love/blueberries", "/I/love/oranges"]

tempArr = []

str.each do |x|
    tempArr << x.split("/")
end
(tempArr[0] & tempArr[1] & tempArr[2]).join('/') #=> "/I/love"
```